# Dynamically find unpaid invoices

Tags: sql-server

How can I dynamically find un-paid invoices from tables bellow:

Invoices Table

```
InvoiceID,  Date        CustomerID,     Amount
1           06/01/2022      1           5000.00
2           08/03/2022      1           4000.00
3           08/25/2022      1           3000.00
4           09/05/2022      1           4500.00
5           09/25/2022      1           4500.00
6           010/10/2022     1           2000.00
7           11/20/2022      1           2500.00
```

Payments Table:-

```
PaymentID    Date       CustomerID      Amount
1           06/10/2022      1           3000.00     
2           06/25/2022      1           4000.00
3           07/15/2022      1           2000.00
4           09/10/2022      1           3000.00
5           10/22/2022      1           4000.00
6           10/24/2022      1           1500.00
7           10/28/2022      1           1000.00
8           11/14/2022      1            500.00
```

Comment: First of all, I guess, you need to describe what means "un-paid invoices"

Comment: How do you match payment to invoice ?

Comment: What do you mean by you want to dynamically do this?

Comment: We have to match payment by CustomerID. there is no invoice reference.

Comment: You need to at least describe your business rules. Do you only do exact matches?

Comment: `there is no invoice reference` That is a basic and HUGE design flaw. But what does "match" actually mean? What is the desired result of your given sample data? Trying to find invoices that are not completely paid?

Comment: @SMor Yes i want to find invoices that are not completely paid.

Comment: But how, exactly do you propose to do this? In your example data, is the first invoice paid? what about the second one?

Answer (score 1):

Try to start with this:

```
SELECT I.CustomerID
     , I.AmountTotal-ISNULL(P.AmountTotal,0) as AmountDiff
  FROM
     ( SELECT CustomerID
            , SUM(Amount) AmountTotal
         FROM <invoices_table>
        GROUP
           BY CustomerID
     ) I
 LEFT
OUTER 
 JOIN
    ( SELECT CustomerID
           , SUM(Amount) AmountTotal
        FROM <payments_table>
       GROUP
          BY CustomerID
    ) P
   ON I.CustomerID = P.CustomerID
WHERE I.AmountTotal <= P.AmountTotal
```